# Merge multiple zip files in to one

Tags: zip, cat, merge

I have over a hundred .zip files that I need to be merged into one. I have found that a possibility is to use:

```
cat "filename1.zip" "filename2.zip" "filenamen.zip">"merged_file.zip"
```

This gives me a file with the same size as the other's combined, but upon extraction, it gives an [error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AKrx3.png).

Is there something I am still doing wrong or is there a better way to do this?

Comment: Take a look at **zipmerge**: https://linux.die.net/man/1/zipmerge

Comment: @ajgringo619 this looks like you could/should create an answer from this comment.

Comment: This is actually mentioned in the link in the answer already given.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://superuser.com/questions/92963/how-to-combine-merge-zip-files

You have to extract all files and rezip them.
Otherwise you just create a binary merge which is not usable by the .Zip-Applications.

Comment: Cheers! This worked brilliantly.